# JsonConvert Class which is inheritance with a list

Tags: c#, json

I am using the code below for populating a list

```
 public class Group : List<Body>
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Group(string title)
        {
            Title = title;
        }
    }
    public class Body
    {
       public string Name { get; set; }
    }

 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var items = new List<Group> {
            new Group("Title")
            {
                new Body { Name = "Dimitris" } }
        };
        var jsonstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);

    }
```

My result is

```
 [[{"Name":"Dimitris"}]]
```

It doesnt get the title property. Is there any way which i can fix this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212892/discussion-on-question-by---jsonconvert-class-which-is-inhe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly not every object can be serialized into valid json. And as I said in the comments what you want (something that has both a title property but is also a list) cannot be presented in valid json (in json something can have properties `{}` or something can be a list `[]` but not both), there are more structures that cannot be represented in valid json (circular dependencies for example) but sadly this is one of them.

Now I understand the need to inherit `List<Group>` for the `ListView` so this poses a problem. However this is not a problem that can't be worked around.

You need to separate the json from the models you bind to your views (this is in general a good practice imo). So you create an object that carries the data and can be serialized into valid json:

```
public class BodyGroupDto
{
    public string Title;
    public List<Body> Items;
}
```

This can now be represented by the following json:

```
[{
    "Title": "SomeTitle",
    "Items": [{
        "Name": "Dimitris"
    }]
}]
```

Now that we have the ability to send the data with json we still need to be able to convert our data object to the actual `Group` object we want to use in the view.

One way to do this is to add another constructor to the `Group` class so we can pass it both a title and items:

```
public class Group : List<Body>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Group(string title)
    {
        Title = title;
    }

    public Group(string title, IEnumerable<Body> items) : base(items)
    {
        Title = title;
    }
}
```

And now we can convert this inside the Xamarin Forms application, for example that could look like this:

```
public List<Group> GetGroups(string json)
{
    var bodyGroupList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BodyGroupDto>>(json);

    return bodyGroupList.Select(bodyGroup => new Group(bodyGroup.Title, bodyGroup.Items)).ToList();
}
```

And if you ever need to convert the other way around you could do something like this:

```
public string GetBodyGroupDtoListJson(List<Group> groups)
{
    var bodyGroupList = groups.Select(group => new BodyGroupDto
    {
        Title = group.Title,
        Items = group.ToList()
    }).ToList();

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyGroupList);
}
```

Hope this helps and good luck with your project

Comment: Thank you, i have tested and it works very well, that is that i was need. Thank you.